# How do I update a record with tortoise orm?

Tags: python, database, fastapi, pydantic, tortoise-orm

I am trying to update a record in the database with tortoise orm. My code is the following:

```
async def update(
        self,
        id: Any,
        obj_in: UpdateSchemaType 
        ) -> ModelType:
        db_obj: ModelType = await self.model.filter(id = id).first()
        data_update = jsonable_encoder(obj_in, exclude_unset=True)
        db_obj_update = await db_obj.update_from_dict(data_update)
        return db_obj_update
```

UpdateSchemaType is a pydantic model and ModelType is a tortoise model.

I am using a path operation with put in fastapi:

```
@users_router.put(
    '/{user_id}',
    name = "Update user"
)
async def update_user(user_id: int, user_update: schemas.UserUpdate):
    'Update user'
    return await crud.user.update(user_id, user_update)
```

When I ran my api I don't get any error, but the registry is not updated!! What am I doing wrong? Or how should I do it to make it useful and efficient?

Comment: Is `update` a method of the `ModelType` class? Please try to provide [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) code in your questions. That means syntactically complete including relevant `import`-statements.

Answer (score 3):

From documentation of `update_from_dict` method:

> This will ignore any extra fields, **and NOT update the model with them**,
> but will raise errors on bad types or updating Many-instance relations.

So you need to make `await object.save()` after `update_from_dict`.

Comment: Also `update_from_dict` method is synchronous.